Establishing mutual TLS connection between Akamai CDN and origin servers
I'm looking to establish mutual TLS between Akamai CDN and origin servers.  All the documentation from Akamai seems to focus on mutual TLS between the end user and the CDN.  Is it possible to force mutual TLS between the CDN and the origin servers?

Akamai does not currently provide self-serviceable TLS mutual authentication between Edge and Origin.
Depending on your requirements, you may try alternative authentication or filtering solutions such as IP allow list or auth based on HTTP request header.
If mTLS to Origin is a hard requirement, you should discuss this directly with Akamai.
